# problem with array "how to make it in the same line"

Tags: math-mode, vertical-alignment, arrays

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{amsmath,amssymb,amsthm} 


\begin{document}

let 
$
\begin{array}{cccc}
f: & \mathbb{R}&\longrightarrow &]-1,1[\\
&x&\mapsto & \dfrac{x}{1+|x|}
\end{array}
$ 
be a continuous function 

\end{document}
```

can I put $f$ in the same line of the texte ?

Comment: You might want to use the interval package to format that `] - 1,1[`, note how in _all_ the examples below, the minus has the wrong spacing (because `] ` is used in a wrong context. The interval package let's you use this syntax while also making signs appear the correct way and not like here where it acts as an addition

Answer (score 3):

I would do that with `aligned`– simpler code and better spacing.  A small improvement with `colon` in the place of a real colon (better spacing) and the `\mfrac` command, preferably to `\dfrac` for online maths:

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{mathtools, amssymb, amsthm}
\usepackage{nccmath}

\begin{document}

let
$ \begin{aligned}[t]
f\colon \mathbb{R}&\longrightarrow ]-1,1[\\[-0.5ex]
x & \longmapsto \mfrac{x}{1+|x|}
\end{aligned}\; $
be a continuous function

\end{document}
```

[image]

Answer (score 2):

`array` has an optional argument to specify which line of the array should be placed on the baseline of the surrounding text, so just do `\begin{array}[t]{cccc}`. `t` for top, aligns the first row of the `array` with the text.

[image]

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{amsmath,amssymb,amsthm} 


\begin{document}

let 
$
\begin{array}[t]{cccc}
f: & \mathbb{R}&\longrightarrow &]-1,1[\\
&x&\mapsto & \dfrac{x}{1+|x|}
\end{array}
$ 
be a continuous function 

\end{document}
```

Comment: what it means [t] please?

Comment: @PolineSandra I edited my answer a bit after first posting it, is it still unclear?

Answer (score 0):

Considering that the tag is also `arrays` (peraphs is off-topic with lot of sincerity) you could use also `tikz-cd` or a matrix. My proposal is this MWE. 
[image]

```
\documentclass[a4paper,12pt]{article}
\usepackage{mathtools}
\usepackage{tikz-cd}
\usepackage{amssymb}
\usepackage{lipsum}

\begin{document}
let \begin{tikzcd}[column sep=.15in,row sep=-.1in]
f\colon \mathbb{R} \arrow[r] & {]-1,1[}         \\
x \arrow[r, maps to]         & \frac{x}{1+|x|}
\end{tikzcd} be a continuous function \lipsum[1]
\end{document}
```

Of course, you should take into account that the two mathematical lines affect in the space colored with the red color if there is more text.